# My Asp.net application wont redirect to my desired page

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I have a login form where a user enters their login details and a query runs through database and verifies their credentials and redirects them to a new page. However the user is not redirected to the new page however the url changes to the desired page. I used Chrome and FireFox thinking it may be the browser but it is doing the same thing. Please see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB30m.png) and my code is below.

```
public void LWAPLogin(string username, string password)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tlcString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string wrongCredentials = "Username does not exist. Or password is incorrect";
        string query = "Select Username, Password from LWAP where Username=@user AND Password=@password;";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {

            command.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = username;
            command.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = password;

            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                    Response.Redirect("LWAPHome.aspx");
                else
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + wrongCredentials + "');", true);

                dr.Close();
            }
            //connection.con.Close();
        }
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: that overload of Redirect always throws a `ThreadAbortedException`. I obviously don't see the rest of your code but I can see that `con.Close()` will never get called. Do this instead:  `Response.Redirect(url, false);` 
 `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`

Comment: Unrelated to question but I'd strongly recommend that you **not** store passwords in your DB in plain text. Best practice is to use a hash algorithm (not SHA1) and a salt. Then your `@password` should contain the generated hash of `password` to compare with the hash in the DB. Also, I hope that connection is in HTTPS or that password is being transmitted in plain text...